# Shared ViewModel in scope of parent fragment using Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to use the same instance of ViewModel in Parent Fragment and its children, using Navigation Component. The hierarchy is as follows: Single Activity that has navigationHost. This host has 3 child fragments, A, B and C. The last fragment has also navigationHost with 2 fragments: X and Y. The below graph illustrates the hierarchy.

[image: Fragments hierarchy]

Expected: 
I would like to share the same instance of fragment C ViewModel with fragment X and Y.

Current: 
The ViewModel of fragment C is initialized twice: Once when fragment C is initialized and second time when fragment X is initialized. The Fragment X is set as a default destination in the fragment C nav graph. When I am changing the default destination to Y, the ViewModel is initialized in C and Y.

What I tried already:
In child viewModels I use this:

```
        val viewModel: ParentViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(findNavController().getViewModelStoreOwner(R.id.parent_graph)).get(
            ParentViewModel::class.java
        )
```

In parent viewModel I use this:

```
    val viewModel by viewModels<ParentViewModel>()
```

I've also tried to inject the viewModel using Koin sharedViewModel with scope of fragment:

```
val viewModel by sharedViewModel<ParentViewModel>(from = { parentFragment!! })
```

Also no luck.

Is it possible or maybe it is a bug in navigation library?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `NavHostFragment` is a fragment itself, so your structure is actually

```
Fragment C -> NavHostFragment -> Fragment X
                              -> Fragment Y
```

I.e., the `parentFragment` you get from Fragment X is **not** Fragment C - it is the `NavHostFragment` you added in between the two.

Therefore if you want to get a `ViewModel` from Fragment C, you'd need to use `requireParentFragment().requireParentFragment()` - the parent of your `NavHostFragment` is Fragment C.

Comment: That works, thanks  . I used the koin `sharedViewModel(from = { requireParentFragment().requireParentFragment() })`
Can that result be achived when using `getViewModelStoreOwner` ? 
As I understand creating the ViewModel in the scope of the nested navigation graph will give me the scope of the navHost, which is different fragment than FragmentC.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot find a parameter with this name: from
------------update----------------

for those facing the same issue, check [here](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/785) koin issue discuss about, and maybe [here](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/442) might be helpful.

I'm using

```
//child fragment    
    private val viewModel: TripParentViewModel by viewModel(owner = { ViewModelOwner.Companion.from(requireParentFragment().requireParentFragment().viewModelStore)})

//parent fragment
private val parentViewModel by viewModel<TripParentViewModel>()
```

as solution,

```
class TripParentViewModel:ViewModel() {

    var count = 0
    fun test(){
        when(count){
            0 -> Timber.d("first click")
            1 -> Timber.d("second click")
            2 -> Timber.d("third click")
        }
        Timber.d(count.toString())
        count++
    }
}
```

currently, I run this when change fragment, I didn't see any problem so far, if anything goes wrong, I will update here

- koin_version = "2.2.1"
- navigation_version = "2.3.5"