Koin: getting instance of viewmodel from parent fragment using an interface/abstract class
I've declared an abstract viewModel (let's say AnimalsViewModel), two viewModels extend it (DogViewModel, CatViewModel)
the corresponding fragments (DogFragment, CatFragment) host a common fragment (AnimalFragment) that needs the instance of whatever AnimalViewModel the parent fragment is using.
But how can I get it in AnimalFragment? I tried this:
class AnimalFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel by lazy {
            requireParentFragment().getViewModel<AnimalViewModel>()
    }
}

but it doesn't work as koin doesn't find the instance owned by the parent and throws an error stating that it doesn't find a provider for AnimalViewModel (obviously, since is abstract). I tried to make it an interface to no avail.
Is there any way to achieve this?
EDIT:
to clarify, let's say DogFragment has an instance of DogViewModel with id 1 and CatFragment has CatViewModel with id 2, AnimalFragment inside inside DogFragment should receive viewModel #1 and the one inside CatFragment should receive #2.
The problem is not getting the viewModel in the correct scope but getting the viewModel using an abstract class as identifier.
this works perfectly but I don't want to add a parameter to AnimalFragment to know which viewModel it should request
private val viewModel by lazy {
        
            requireParentFragment().getViewModel<DogViewModel>()
     

    }


try doing requireParentFragment().requireParentFragment() as suggested from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356505/shared-viewmodel-in-scope-of-parent-fragment-using-navigation-component and here https://medium.com/@kennethchangla/koin-share-viewmodel-in-parent-fragment-and-child-fragment-e80ad1fe1a38

I have also seen by viewModels(ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() }) used

@tyczj I don't think that's the issue. AnimalFragment is correctly asking its parent for its instance of the viewModel but can't find it since I request an abstract class. If I specify the implementation I want it works correctly

I ended up defining an interface which provides a viewmodel of the required abstract type. It's not ideal but it's better than passing arguments around or mentioning the parent fragments in the child.
interface AnimalContainer {
    abstract val viewModel: AnimalViewModel
}

class AnimalFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel by lazy {
        (requireParentFragment() as? AnimalContainer)?.viewModel
            ?: error("AnimalFragment not allowed in container ${requireParentFragment()}")
    }
}

